# Using a variable to specify formatting a float using str.format

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

I would like to use a variable to specify the number of decimals to format as in this case: (python 3.4.6)

```
print(str.format('{0:.intVariableName}',1.2345678))
```

Comment: print(str.format('{0:.3}',1.2345678)) .. works, I would like to use a variable instead of 3.

Comment: also working:  `print('{:.{}}'.format(1.2345678, 3))` and `print('{:.{var}}'.format(1.2345678, var=3))` - this also omits using explicit indexes for formatting using implicitly order of provided params

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable name as another argument in `format` function:

```
In [29]: print(str.format('{0:.{var}}',1.2345678, var=3))
1.23
```